# click tags for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I noticed the click tags panel wont appear with custom post types. I have a post type called portfolio and I would like to have the click tags panel.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean tags section in the custom post types? If that is what you mean, there is a similar question here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62260/how-to-add-tags-to-custom-post-type

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the `post_tag` taxonomy for your post type:

```
<?php
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'portfolio'  );
```

Now you've got `post_tag` taxonomy shared with regular posts and other post types for which tags where registered.

If you want to use custom taxonomy for example, *portfolio-tag*, which belongs to the *portfolio* custom post type only:

```
<?php
function portfolio_tags()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Portfolio Tag',
        // More labels goes here
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        // More arguments goes here
    );

    // agrs: taxonomy key, custom post type, arguments
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-tags', 'portfolio', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_tags', 0 );
```

For `register_taxonomy()` arguments [see the Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/).

Comment: Thank you but I already did that. I can add tags for that taxonomy its just that I dont get the click tags panel that appears on other post types so instead I have to type them one by one in the tags box.